# Apple Watch crash detection

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, crashlytics

I have Apple Watch app and I need to detect the crashes in it.

For my iPhone, I'm using Crashlytics to detect the crashes. How can I use the same for apple watch?

Is it possible to detect the crashes in Apple Watch using Crashlytics for my app?

Also, let me know if any other services available for the same.

Comment: You can attach the watch app process from xcode and after that you can able to debug the watch app.

Comment: @userar: It was happening with the users, this will be not possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash allows you to record and upload the watchOS crashes.

We've got it working with Hockey and I'll update here if I manage to get it uploading to Crashlytics.

Comment: Looking at the code it does not catch every crash, as it is not possible to detect Mach Exceptions or Signals as Apple removed those APIs from watchOS. So all you can get are unhandled exceptions which are only a (small) subset of all crashes.

Comment: Yup, from my perspective, it's currently better than just using the Xcode crash organizer despite its shortcomings.